# CONFLICT Get a input text field when select box option value

Tags: jquery, conflict

Reference from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cqjJy/)

this method does not work when jquery conflicts with prototype , any suggestion?

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(window).load(function() { 
        $('#trade_type').change(function() {
            if( $(this).val() == '6') {
                $('body').append('<input id="promo" type="text" />');
            }
            else {
                $('#promo').remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert `$` to `jQuery` or wrap your code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {...});`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#trade_type').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '6') {
                $('body').append('<input id="promo" type="text" />');
            } else {
                $('#promo').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```